# GlobalKey with an ArrayList

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a generated GlobalKey list, and I stucked with this:

`final List<GlobalKey> keys = List<GlobalKey>.generate(optionalChars.length, (index) => GlobalKey(debugLabel: "key$index"));`

Any way to use it in a list?

```
 Container(
        key: index != -1 ? keys[index] : null,
```

And I got the same error

> The following assertion was thrown building Container(bg:
>   BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffdadada)), constraints:
>   BoxConstraints(w=360.0, h=270.0)): Multiple widgets used the same
>   GlobalKey.

Anyone can help?

Comment: read `debugLabel` description and try to change it to simple `=> GlobalKey();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens if you use the same GlobalKey on different widgets. I replicated the code you gave and had no error except for when I attached the same GlobalKey object to another widget. So if you're using `keys` somewhere else this error will occur. You can't reuse the GlobalKey on two widgets at the same time.